# C++ Templates with function declaration/ protype and definition

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to templates, [was reading up on them](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/) and [found a great video tutorial on them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfxa0AhtLLk).

Furthermore, I know that there are two types of templates, class and function templates. However, in my snippet of code I only wanted to use a function template instead of a class template, but I wanted to have a function declaration and definition that makes use of the template. It seems a little weird to have the same code for the template in the function definition and declaration (I read a thread on this on the cpp website, but I can only post two links right now).

Is this the correct syntax for using a template with a function declaration and definition?

- A.

Here is the snippet of consolidated code:

```
class GetReadFile {
public:
    // Function Declaration
    template <size_t R, size_t C>   // Template same as definition
    bool writeHistory(double writeArray[R][C], string path);
};

// Function Definition
template <size_t R, size_t C>      // Template same as declaration
bool GetReadFile::writeHistory(double writeArray[R][C], string path){...}
```

Comment: That's right, or you can define the function inline (inside the class) directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling it the right way, the syntax works well for me:

```
GetReadFile grf;
double array[5][8];    
grf.writeHistory<5,8>(array,"blah");
```

See [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c33fe3c1f44c2978).

Note though:
Simply calling that method without specifying the actual array dimensions, these can't be automatically deduced by the compiler:

```
grf.writeHistory(array,"blah");
```

Fails with

```
main.cpp:24:34: error: no matching function for call to 'GetReadFile::writeHistory(double [5][8], const char [5])'  
  grf.writeHistory(array,"blah");
                              ^
  ...
main.cpp:10:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:24:34: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'R'
 grf.writeHistory(array,"blah");
```

See the [alternate demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05dfb3df4edfbc63).